# Access to projectDir from karma test?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, karma-runner, gulp-karma

Within a karma test beforeEach) block I would like to access (read) a file from the project directory.  However, I do not know how to get access to that directory, since process.cwd() returns the directory the test is running in, which is a random private dir assigned by node or gulp.

How can I find what the project dir is within a running test?

```
describe.only('convertClaimTypes', function () {
    var claimTypes;

    before(function () {
        var base = process.cwd();
        claimTypes = fs.readFileSync(path.join(base, 'build/resources/claimTypes.json'));
        claimTypes = JSON.parse(claimTypes);
    });
...
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using [`__dirname`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) in place of `process.cwd()` as it gives you the directory of the current file rather than the directory of the executable.

For example, if your tests are within a directory `/test` and `/build` is a directory within the root of your application, access `/build` from `/test` like so:

```
path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/');
```

Comment: Tried that, that variable doesn't exist in the context of the running test.

Comment: It is a global variable maintained by Node, so I can't see why this would be the case. Perhaps it is that you are not writing the variable name correctly? It has two underscores at the beginning.

Comment: That's a pain. Thanks for the link. In which case it looks like you will need to hardcode an absolute path. You could have this path in a configuration file.

Comment: Thats what I was originally doing, but I have two machines with different paths to myproject

Comment: This is quite common. You can have different configs for each machine and use the NODE_ENV environment variable to denote which to use.